# Conditional c.d.f

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables, with

$f(x;\lambda)= \frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}, x \gt 0$
$f(y;\mu) = \frac{1}{\mu}e^{-y/\mu}, y \gt 0$
Let $Z = min(X,Y)$ and $W =1$ if $Z = X$, $W =0$ if $Z = Y$

Find the conditional c.d.f of $Z$ given $W = 1$ ?

Here is my trial:

$P(Z \le z| W=1) = 1 - P(Z \ge z| W=1) = 1 -\frac{P(Z \ge z, Y \ge X)}{P(Y \ge X)} = 1- \frac{P(X \ge z, Y \ge z, Y \ge X)}{P(Y \ge X)}$
$ = 1 - P(X \ge z, Y \ge z) = 1 - e^{(\frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu})z}$

Is there anything wrong in my solution ?

Comment: Please explain why you think that $$\frac{P(X \geqslant z, Y \geqslant z, Y \geqslant X)}{P(Y \geqslant X)}= P(X \geqslant z, Y \geqslant z)$$

Comment: @Did, I think it is because X and Y are independent..

Comment: No. There is no theorem in your notes saying that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this holds.

Comment: $X,Y$ being independent does not mean they will still be independent *under condition that* $Y\geqslant X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went awry at the second last equality; it is not true.   $~X,Y~$ being independent does not mean they will still be independent *under condition that* $~Y\geqslant X~$.

You will need to perform the following integrations.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\geqslant X\geqslant 0) ~&=~ \int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty (\mu\lambda)^{-1} e^{-y/\mu-x/\lambda}\mathop{d}y\mathop d{x}
\\[3ex]
\mathsf P(Y\geqslant z,X\geqslant z, Y\geqslant X) &=~ \mathsf P(Y\geqslant X\geqslant z)
\\[1ex] & = ~ \int_z^\infty\int_x^\infty (\mu\lambda)^{-1} e^{-y/\mu-x/\lambda}\mathop{d}y\mathop d{x}\end{align}$$

---

**Hint:** clearly the first is a special case of the second when $z=0$, so save some work.

Comment: Oh I get it ! Thanks !

Comment: @ZHANGYUE After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).